# Weird usage of "alles"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have encountered this paragraph:

> Frauen und Männer sind ähnlich stark in den Berufsgruppen der Ärzte und Apotheker, im Bankwesen, aber auch in den Geistes- und Naturwissenschaften vertreten. **Alles** Bereiche, in denen früher vor allem Männer tätig waren.

*Alles Bereiche*? What does it mean literally in English? From context I can understand that it means "all the domains, in which ..." What does *alles* mean here, taking in consideration that it's conjugated to the word *Bereiche*?

Comment: Can you not simply translate it literally to English, especially with context? "Banking, liberal arts, STEM -- all [of these are] areas in which predominantly men used to work". Or am I falling again for a Germanism?

Comment: But it does make perfect sense.

Comment: I think a more natural way to say it in English is "All of which are".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, the OP is asking us: "What does it mean literally?" It doesn't make sense to me when you ask the OP back: "Can you not translate it literally". It's like circular reasoning.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Rereading that I suspect that there is not a literal translation at all. My attempt is actually not a literal translation: In "all of these", "all" is arguably a plural. The construct "das alles *sind*" has no direct translation afaics -- "all of that are funny things" sounds too funny --, and that's probably what the OP stumbled upon.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica If you add the necessary part "of these are" which is missing in the original text, you give the best explanation why this can't be translated literally ;-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> ***Alles Bereiche***, in denen früher vor allem Männer tätig waren.

This is actually an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) where the two words *das sind* were omitted.

> *Das sind **alles Bereiche***, in denen früher vor allem Männer tätig waren.
>
> (***All** of these are **areas*** where primarily men used to work.)

---

**Addendum:**

As hinted in the comments, *alles* in the above construction supplements *das*. This should be distinguished from the following construction in that *alle* is an attribute of *Bereiche*:

> *Das sind **alle Bereiche***, in denen früher vor allem Männer tätig waren.
>
> (*These are **all areas*** where primarily men used to work.)

In the previous version, I had not thought about the importance of this distinction, as not even the [DeepL translator](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Das%20sind%20alles%20Bereiche%2C%20...) translates it correctly.

Comment: Why wasn't it written: alle Bereiche? Why the alles instead of alle?

Comment: @MarioBedoun: "Alle Bereiche [...]" would mean "All of the areas where men used to work", which is not the intended meaning. All of the fields mentioned were male-dominated, but there were more such fields which are not mentioned.

Comment: *Das sind {alle Bereiche}* = 'these are {all areas} (that ...)' // *Das sind {alle**s**} {Bereiche}* = ***{Das} {alles}** sind Bereiche* = '**{all of these}** are areas (that ...)'

Comment: Just to underscore this, it wouldn't be surprising to see the equivalent fragment _"All areas where primarily men used to work"_ used in exactly the same way in English.

Comment: @Spencer, good point. However, then it becomes ambiguous, because you cannot make the distinction anymore, can you?

Comment: @BjörnFriederich Well, that's English for you. As in so many other cases, you can infer which one it is by context, in this case a list of occupations preceding the sentence.

Answer (score 8):

As @BjörnFriedrich wrote: it's an ellipsis where *das sind* was omitted.

> *Das sind* alles Bereiche, ...

That's already half of the story. The remaining question is why it says *alles* and not *alle*. The answer is that *alles* is a supplement to *das* here (not an attribute to *Bereiche*) that can take several positions in the sentence:

> - Das sind **alles** Bereiche (in denen ...)
> - **Alles** das sind Bereiche ...
> - Das **alles** sind Bereiche ...

It means:

> **All of these** are areas that ...

The exact translation can change according to the context, but the meaning stays the same:

> - Das alles und noch viel mehr ...
> - All of that (that all) and even much more ...

The *Dudengrammatik* covers this topic in § 410, subsections (viii) and (ix).

Answer (score 1):

"Alles" does not refer to "Bereiche" in this case. It refers to the previously mentioned domains - and can be translated as "*everything previously mentioned (is/are)*".

Answer (score 0):

It means in this context "all the mentioned occupations".